# add new text field on + button click in a view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS-swift. I need to add new text field after clicking `"+"` button.

Please check this image:
[image]

There is one text field already. I need to add

```
1) one text filed
2) one + button beside new text field
3) - button beside old text field
```

clicking `"+"`, will add and clicking `"-"` will remove text field.

any help would be appreciated....

Comment: please share what you've tried already

Comment: not done anything yet, was just googling.

Comment: use `tableView`, add a cell with textfield after pressed `+` ?

Comment: @Tj3n ok - I'm trying. as I'm new , I need to learn tableView and adding cell.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use Table view.
2. Design TableViewCell which have textfield and button and custom
   twxtfield class must have property for define + or - button should
   be added to cell and this property also helpful to handle -/+ with
   one button.
3. When + button clicked you need to add one row to table view and on -
   clicked you need to remove row from tableview

you can refer to add/remove [check it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Answer (score 2):

1) You can easily achieve it by tableview.

2) One row, in which textfield and + button is there.

3) Once you click on add button, add new row with textfield and - button.

4) Once you click on -, remove row from tableview.

**EDIT**

Here is demo link, how to add/remove row in tableview
http://objectivecwithsuraj.blogspot.in/2012/10/uitableview-add-or-remove-rows.html